# getting distance between two locations(road distance) in android not working on real device

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, gps, location, google-directions-api

I'm finding road distance between two location.i'm getting correct output on emulator.but when i execute code on device its just after opening app its giving force close.
i'm not getting why this is happening for device.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener,OnClickListener{

private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;   
private Spinner mSprPlaceType;  
private String[] mPlaceType=null;
private double mLatitude=0;
private double mLongitude=0;
private LatLng currentLatLng;
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    mContext=this;
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "oncreate..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!enabled) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
      startActivity(intent);
    } 
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(location!=null){
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

    String str=GetRoutDistane(mLaitude, mLongitude,  END_LATITUDE,END_LONGITUDE);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "distance..."+str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public String GetRoutDistane(double startLat, double startLong, double endLat, double endLong)
{
    String Distance = "error";
    String Status = "error";
    try {

        parser_Json PJ=new parser_Json(mContext);
        JSONObject jsonObj = parser_Json.getJSONfromURL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+startLat+","+startLong+"&destination="+endLat+","+endLong+"&sensor=true");
        Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "status.."+Status,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK"))
        {
            JSONArray routes = jsonObj.getJSONArray("routes"); 
            JSONObject zero = routes.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray legs = zero.getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject zero2 = legs.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject dist = zero2.getJSONObject("distance");
            Distance = dist.getString("text");
        }
        else
        {
            Distance = "Too Far";
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Distance;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    currentLatLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button)v;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, b.getText() + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

xml file-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:text="get distance between two locations" />
```

Comment: Where did you get parser_Json ?!

Answer (score 0):

did you try finding the distance between 2 points which were recorded at an interval of say a few minutes or few meters?

Keep a track of the path traveled, instead of calculating the distance between start and end point, calculate the distance of the intermediate points, the sum of the distances is your final distance.

Like you want to travel from Pune to Mumbai, you keep on saving the locations every few minutes and calculate the intermediate distances...

**EDIT** I assume you are travelling on the path and not just direct calculation.

Comment: the problem is not distance or location to calculate,its working correctly on emulator not on real device.please go through my question again.

Comment: @yuva  so what problem are you getting? your question is bit confusing.

Comment: @yuva please paste the logcat so that we might be able to make out which request is taking time..